# How to make Ramda.is() function return another type

Tags: typescript, generics, ramda.js

I am using `Ramda.is` to check types. But by default when i use it with array (`Ramda.is(Array)`) it returns `val is unknown[]` type. If there are any options to make it `return val is any[]` using generics for examle. Or the only option is to do something like that `(val: any): val is any[] => R.is(Array)(val)`.

[image: The problem is here]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following the question.  `R.is` returns a boolean.  You can't make it return any other type.

Comment: @ScottSauyet ‘R.is’, as we can see from the image, returns ‘val is unknown[]’. I need to make it return ‘val is any[]’

Comment: There's some confusion here.  [`R.is`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.28.0/source/is.js) can *only* return a boolean.  You might show some more code and not just an image of some output.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have discovered that R.is return a Boolean, but not in my project. I seems that we have different versions of ramda

Comment: That screenshot looks much more like some hover help from an IDE than a return from a function.  Are you sure you're interpreting things correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `R.is` is:

```
is(ctor: any, val: any): boolean;
is(ctor: any): (val: any) => boolean;
```

So the return value is always a Boolean.

However, in your case you don't care about the result of `R.is`, you want to set the type of the value passed to `val` to be `any[]` if `R.is` returns `true`.

To do that, you can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that will "mark" the passed value:

```
const isArrayWithType = (val: any): val is any[] => is(Array, val);
```

And if we use it as a guard, TS will now know that whatever we passed as `val` is of type `any[]`:

```
const arr: unknown = [1, 2, 3];

if (isArrayWithType(arr)) {
  arr.push(4); // arr type is any[]
} else {
  arr.push(5); // arr type is unknown
}
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r-is-with-type-predicate-kd2kgc?file=/src/index.ts)